# how to get this POST to work in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to have a button on the front-end of my rails app which shows a list of links. I want them to be able to click "Add to Favorite"

Right now I'm struggling on just making it work without AJAX, but eventually I'm going to add that in once I get the fallback working (just a regular link, right?.. then in the js i use return false; and then use ajax)

Right now, i dont see anything that is wrong, but its not adding a favorite when i click it. Any help would be appreciated

routes:

```
  root  :to => 'home#index'

  resources :resources, :except => [:index]
  resources :profiles,  :only   => [:show]
  resources :favorites, :only   => [:create, :destroy]

  match '/learn',    :to => 'pages#learn'
  match '/contact',  :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/requests', :to => 'pages#requests'
```

favorites Controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @favorite = Favorite.new(:resource_id => params[:id], :user_id => current_user.id)
    if @favorite.valid?
      @favorite.save
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # also must find by user as well...
    @favorite = Favorite.find_by_resource_id(params[:id])
    @favorite.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

heres my Views code that actually shows the 'add favorite' link:

```
<%= link_to favorites_path(resource), :method => :post, :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini" do %>
  <i class="icon-star icon-white" rel="tooltip" title="add to favorites"></i> Add to favorites
<% end  %>
```

when i hover over it the url shows up as site.com/favorites.3 --- not sure if this is correct?

Comment: what happens on the server side when you click the link? do you get output from request in the console?

Comment: you should check https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails if you don't already know it. :) It's a nice gem for bootstrap

Comment: What's the result of your rake routes?  The hover link is clearly wrong.

Comment: favorites POST   /favorites(.:format)          favorites#create
                favorite DELETE /favorites/:id(.:format)      favorites#destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default create actions are post in rails hence rather than changing default behaviour add new action for your purpose.

**inside routes**

```
resources :favorites, :only   => [:destroy] do
 get :add, :on => :collection 
end
```

**view***

```
<%= link_to add_favorites_path(:id => resource), :class => "btn btn-warning btn-mini" do %>
  <i class="icon-star icon-white" rel="tooltip" title="add to favorites"></i> Add to favorites
<% end  %>
```

controller `create` action will get `renamed` to `add`

Comment: I guess I'm still confused. If I'm not trying to rename an action do I still do this? I thought if its an ajax call to create a 'favorite' it would be FavoritesController#create

Comment: could you explain what this is doing? add_favorites_path(:id => resource) .. it worked and i have no idea why :/ I also dont know what this is  get :add, :on => :collection . i really appreciate your help'!

Comment: we defined get route for url "/favourites/add"..for more info just go through guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that using a form to POST data instead of a link that makes GET, or adding this route should make it as well

```
match "/favorites/add/:id" => "favorites#create"
```

Comment: I'm telling it to post in the link_to (see last block of code). The route already is expecting POST because I used resources :favorites

Comment: Ok, i think the problem its favorites_path(resource), because it seams you are passing resource as a favorite, so it tries to get the favorite with that resource id.